# Alterar estilo de linha no autoplot

Tags: r

Estou com dúvida em como alterar o estilo de uma única linha em um gráfico que contêm duas linhas no autoplot no r. Consigo mudar o estilo usando o comando ts.linetype, porém ele altera o estilo das duas linhas e não somente de uma, conforme gostaria. O que devo fazer? Encaminho a foto do gráfico e o código

```
autoplot(PMC, facets = FALSE, size=1, linetype = 'dashed') +

  scale_x_date(breaks = date_breaks("1 months"),

  labels = date_format("%b/%Y")) + theme_minimal()+

  guides(color=guide_legend(title="PMC")) + 

  scale_linetype_manual(labels = c("Restrita", "Ampliada"), values = c(1, 2))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Caso alguém puder me ajudar, agradeço.

Comment: Olha, `linetype` era pra estar dentro de `aes` para `scale_linetype_manual` poder funcionar. Mas como não sei o nome das suas variáveis ou o formato de PMC não dá pra eu dar uma resposta mais clara. Recomendo colocar uma parte ou exemplo do banco de dados para quem for ajudar poder reproduzir.

Comment: Quanto à pergunta, talvez `linetype = c('dashed', 'dotted')` ou outro estilo à sua escolha. E se houver 3 linhas, passe um vetor com 3 estilos, etc.

Comment: O @JorgeMendes diz *não sei o nome das suas variáveis ou o formato de `PMC`*, isto faz uma diferença enorme. A função `autoplot` é genérica, e o método chamado no código da pergunta depende da classe de `PMC`. Já vi gráficos de métodos do `autoplot` completamente diferentes do gráfico da pergunta.

Comment: Rui, ele não aceita essa forma linetype = c('dashed', 'dotted'). Somente no autoplot não aceita, quando utilizo o geom_line dessa forma dá certo.

Answer (score 1):

```
           PMC.restrita    PMC.ampliada
```

Jan 2018           2.4           4.6

Feb 2018           2.9           5.4

Mar 2018           3.8           6.3

Apr 2018           3.7           7.0

May 2018           3.7           6.8

Jun 2018           3.6           6.7

Jul 2018           3.3           6.5

Aug 2018           3.3           6.4

Sep 2018           2.8           5.9

Oct 2018           2.8           5.7

Nov 2018           2.6           5.5

Dec 2018           2.3           5.0

Jan 2019           2.2           4.7

Feb 2019           2.4           4.9

Mar 2019           1.3           3.9

Apr 2019           1.4           3.5

May 2019           1.3           3.9

Jun 2019           1.1           3.7

Essa é minha base de dados!

Answer (score 0):

Passei seus dados para um arquivo csv, na seguinte forma:

```
date,PMC.restrita,PMC.ampliada
01 Jan 2018,2.4,4.6
01 Feb 2018,2.9,5.4
01 Mar 2018,3.8,6.3
01 Apr 2018,3.7,7.0
01 May 2018,3.7,6.8
01 Jun 2018,3.6,6.7
01 Jul 2018,3.3,6.5
01 Aug 2018,3.3,6.4
01 Sep 2018,2.8,5.9
01 Oct 2018,2.8,5.7
01 Nov 2018,2.6,5.5
01 Dec 2018,2.3,5.0
01 Jan 2019,2.2,4.7
01 Feb 2019,2.4,4.9
01 Mar 2019,1.3,3.9
01 Apr 2019,1.4,3.5
01 May 2019,1.3,3.9
01 Jun 2019,1.1,3.7
```

Não consegui reproduzir teu código com o 'autoplot' e então adaptei o dataframe para conseguir utilizar o ggplot2.

É necessário incluir no aesthetic a variável que discrimina o linetype. Fazendo isso, conseguimos modificar manualmente os tipos das linhas.

```r
df <- read.csv(file = "dados.csv") # Leitura dos dados em csv
df$date <- as.Date(df$date, format="%d %b %Y") # Transformação da variável para tipo date
PMC <- melt(df, id.vars = "date") # Utilizando Melt para 

# Construção do gráfico
ggplot(PMC, aes(x=date, y=value,color = variable, linetype = variable, group=variable)) +
    geom_line() +
    ggtitle("PMC restrita e ampliada acumulada em 12 meses (%)") +
    xlab("Anos") + ylab("Percentual") +
    scale_colour_discrete(labels = c("Restrita", "Ampliada")) +
    scale_linetype_manual(labels = c("Restrita", "Ampliada"), values = c(1, 2))+
    scale_x_date(breaks = scales::date_breaks("1 months"),
                 labels = scales::date_format("%b/%Y")) + theme_minimal()+
    guides(color=guide_legend(title="PMC"), linetype=guide_legend(title="PMC"))
```

[image: alteração de linha no ggplot2]